# How to check a radio button on Angular for Ionic 5?

Tags: radio-button, ionic5

i'm getting the following error:

`core.js:7812 Can't bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-radio'.`

And my code on HTML is:

```
    <ion-list>
      <ion-radio-group value="default" (ionChange)="radioGroupChange($event)">
        <ion-list-header>
          <ion-label>Image language</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>
    
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>SPA</ion-label>
          <ion-radio [checked]="true" slot="start" value="spa"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>RU</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="ru"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>ENG</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="eng"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>

    </ion-list>
```

How to set by default a radio button checked?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well according to the Ionic5 [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio#basic-usage), you have to set the value of the `<ion-radio-group>` to the value of the `<ion-radio>` that you want checked by default.

So get rid of your `[checked]="true"`

Change

`<ion-radio-group value="default" (ionChange)="radioGroupChange($event)">`

to

`<ion-radio-group value="spa" (ionChange)="radioGroupChange($event)">`

to achieve your desired outcome.